# Golang TCP Client Does Not Send `End of Stream` to Java TCP Server

Tags: java, go, tcp

I'm writing a simple Golang TCP Client that talks with a Java TCP Server.

I have successfully gotten my Golang Client to send a message to my Java Server.

However, my Java code is expecting an `End of Stream` (where `inputStream.read()` returns `-1`) to know that it's time to stop reading Client messages.

It looks like Golang does not send an `End of Stream` message via `connection.Write()` unless I `Close()` the connection first.

Below is my Java Server code:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 9000;

        // Start listening for messages.
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
            System.out.println("Listening on port " + port + "...");

            // Never stop listening for messages.
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Accept a client connection.
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    // Read message from the client.
                    DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();
                    int input = inputStream.read();

                    while (input != -1) {
                        list.add((byte) input);
                        input = inputStream.read();
                    }

                    byte[] jsonBytes = Bytes.toArray(list);

                    if (jsonBytes.length > 0) {
                        String jsonString = new String(jsonBytes);

                        System.out.println("Received: " + jsonString);

                        // Unmarshal from JSON.
                        Person person = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Person.class);

                        System.out.println("Person: " + person.Name + " " + person.Age);
                    }
                } catch (EOFException e) {
                    // A client has disconnected. Do nothing.
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // A client connection has been terminated unexpectedly. Do nothing.
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Person {
    String Name;
    int Age;
}
```

Below is my Golang Client code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for {
        func() {
            // Dial the Java Server.
            conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:9000")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

            defer conn.Close()

            fmt.Print("Enter Name: ")
            strName, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
            strName = strings.TrimSpace(strName)

            var person Person
            person.Name = strName
            person.Age = 18

            jsonBytes, err := json.Marshal(person)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }

            // Write our message to the connection.
            _, err = conn.Write(jsonBytes)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }

            fmt.Println("Sent: " + string(jsonBytes))
        }()
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to tell Java that we're done writing messages from Golang? Or is there a better way to handle Java x Golang TCP Client-Server connections?

This is quite a problem because one of the basic scenarios for TCP connections is Send-and-Receive:

e.g.

1. Client sends a message and waits for the result.
2. Server processes the message and returns the result.
3. Client does something with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work following @nos' advice to call `CloseWrite()` instead of `Close()`.

Had to change my TCP Connection code a bit, but it works like a charm.

This solution is perfect for my purposes because I only plan to do 1 Send from a Client connection and possibly 1 Read before I Close it.

Many thanks to everyone who helped!

Below is my updated Golang Client code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

// Person struct.
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for {
        func() {
            // Dial the Java Server.
            tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:9000")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }

            conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }

            defer conn.Close()

            fmt.Print("Enter Name: ")
            strName, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
            strName = strings.TrimSpace(strName)

            var person Person
            person.Name = strName
            person.Age = 18

            jsonBytes, err := json.Marshal(person)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }

            // Write our message to the connection.
            _, err = conn.Write(jsonBytes)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }

            // Tell the server that we're done writing.
            err = conn.CloseWrite()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }

            // Read Message From Server code goes here.

            fmt.Println("Sent: " + string(jsonBytes))
        }()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you probably want to make sure your client code reliably closes the socket. But that's not all you should do.

The client process should trigger a TCP FIN as a result of closing the socket.  And the socket should get closed as a result of the client process cleanly exiting.  Not sure why this isn't the case for you.  Are you waiting long enough?

However, so that your server is not indefinitely hung, you need to guard for this condition. Consider the case where there's an active TCP connection between a client and your server. And while the server is awaiting data from the client, the power goes out where the client is at.  Because there's no way for the client to send a FIN, the server connection isn't going to have any traffic.  That TCP connection will stay hung forever unless....

You either set a keep-alive option or a timeout option on the server side.

Keep-alive: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_KEEPALIVE

Timeout: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_TIMEOUT

Comment: I believe when a Client connection gets terminated unexpectedly, the `catch (SocketException e)` line should be able to handle it. As for the Keep-alive and Timeout links, I'll be sure to try them out. Many thanks!

Comment: Correct. But you won't get that socket exception fired unless TCP has detected the connection as failed.  That being said, TCP does not have a magic way of detecting when a remote client disappears (e.g. network cable unplugged) unless there was a timeout waiting for ACK on sent data.

Comment: Thanks for the best practice tip. Ended up going with the Timeout approach since it's more practical. Back to my original problem though, it seems that the issue is with Golang's `connection.Write()` function, because's it's not sending `TCP FIN` unless I close the connection first. This is quite a problem because one of the basic scenarios is 1) Client sends message and waits for the result 2) Server processes the message and returns the result. 3) Client does something with the message.

Comment: @FloatingSunfish That's how the socket API works in all languages for TCP. You get EOF(read() returns -1)  at one end when the other end closes the connection. Keep in mind that TCP is stream based,  not message based. One Write() at one end doesn't neccesarily match up with exactly one Read() at the other end. For your particular scenario, you could perhaps have the client/server use the TCP concept of a half-closed connection. That is, have your client call CloseWrite() instead of Close().

Comment: @FloatingSunfish You have a bit of an impedance mismatch. You need a message protocol such that saying "client sends message" actually means something. But TCP is *not* a message protocol and you shouldn't expect it to act like one. It may be helpful to study the specifications of some protocols layered on top of TCP so you have a better understanding of what TCP does and what your code must do to use TCP properly. You can use the closing of the connection to mark a message boundary, but then only one message per connection is possible.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better than David and nos.

Comment: Got it, I'll see how to get `CloseWrite()` to work in Golang. Yeah, I figured I was doing a communication mismatch because if it's Go x Go `connection.Write()` actually tells the Server that it's done. I'm probably using the wrong Java code for this. Many thanks.